# detectMultiScale parameters in OpenCV 2.4.8 , Java

Tags: java, opencv, parameters

I'm trying to detect faces from a video stream using OpenCV 2.4.8 with Java using detectMultiScale. When searching through the web I noticed two versions of it with different parameter lists. Like [here](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/objdetect/cascade_classifier/cascade_classifier.html):

```
detectMultiScale(image, faceDetections) in [here][1] and face_cascade.detectMultiScale( frame_gray, faces, 1.1, 2, 0|CV_HAAR_SCALE_IMAGE, Size(30, 30) )
```

When I used it inside my code it gives an error :

```
OpenCV Error: Bad flag (parameter or structure field) (Unrecognized or unsupported array type) in cvGetMat
```

When I debug the code I see that error occurs at line:

```
face_cascade.detectMultiScale(frame_gray, faces);
```

I'm confused with these two parameter method because in OpenCV documentation site they have only one method with seven parameters.

```
detectMultiScale(const Mat& image, vector<Rect>& objects, double scaleFactor=1.1, int minNeighbors=3, int flags=0, Size minSize=Size(), Size maxSize=Size())
```

Can anyone please describe what is this two parameter method and does it has any connection with the error in my code. Following is the code I was checking on:

```
 import org.opencv.core.Core;
 import org.opencv.core.Mat;
 import org.opencv.core.MatOfRect;
 import org.opencv.core.Point;
 import org.opencv.core.Rect;
 import org.opencv.core.Scalar;
 import org.opencv.core.Size;
 import org.opencv.highgui.Highgui;
 import org.opencv.highgui.VideoCapture;
 import org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc;
 import org.opencv.objdetect.CascadeClassifier;

 public class FaceDetectSVM {

/**
 * @param args
 */ 

public static void main(String[] args) {

    //load opencv native library
    System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);



    CascadeClassifier face_cascade = new CascadeClassifier("haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml");
    CascadeClassifier eyes_cascade = new CascadeClassifier("haarcascade_eye.xml");
    String window_name = "Capture - Face detection.jpg";

    System.out.println("capture through camera "+Core.VERSION);


    //load the face xml cascade
    if(!face_cascade.load("haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml"))
    {
        System.out.println("Error loading face cascade");
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("Success loading face cascade");
    }

    //load the eyes xml cascade
    if(!eyes_cascade.load("haarcascade_eye.xml"))
    {
        System.out.println("Error loading eyes cascade");
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("Success loading eyes cascade");
    }

    //detect default camera
    VideoCapture capture = new VideoCapture(0);

    if(!capture.isOpened())
    {
        System.out.println("Did not connected to camera.");
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("Conected to camera: "+capture.toString());
    }

    //create new Mat image
    Mat frame = new Mat();
    while(true){
    capture.retrieve(frame);

    Mat frame_gray = new Mat();
    Imgproc.cvtColor(frame, frame_gray, Imgproc.COLOR_BGRA2GRAY);
    Imgproc.equalizeHist(frame_gray, frame_gray);


    MatOfRect faces = new MatOfRect();

    face_cascade.detectMultiScale(frame_gray, faces);


    Rect[] facesArray = faces.toArray();

    for(int i=0; i<facesArray.length; i++)
    {
        Point center = new Point(facesArray[i].x + facesArray[i].width * 0.5, facesArray[i].y + facesArray[i].height * 0.5);
         Core.ellipse(frame, center, new Size(facesArray[i].width * 0.5, facesArray[i].height * 0.5), 0, 0, 360, new Scalar(255, 0, 255), 4, 8, 0);

         Mat faceROI = frame_gray.submat(facesArray[i]);
         MatOfRect eyes = new MatOfRect();

         //-- In each face, detect eyes
         eyes_cascade.detectMultiScale(faceROI, eyes, 1.1, 2, 0,new Size(30,30), new Size());            

         Rect[] eyesArray = eyes.toArray();

         for (int j = 0; j < eyesArray.length; j++)
         {
            Point center1 = new Point(facesArray[i].x + eyesArray[i].x + eyesArray[i].width * 0.5, facesArray[i].y + eyesArray[i].y + eyesArray[i].height * 0.5);
            int radius = (int) Math.round((eyesArray[i].width + eyesArray[i].height) * 0.25);
            Core.circle(frame, center1, radius, new Scalar(255, 0, 0), 4, 8, 0);
         }
    }

    Highgui.imwrite(window_name, frame);
    capture.release();


    }

}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

OpenCV is written in C/C++. Java wrappers allows access to native code via JNI. Unlike C++, Java doesn't support default parameter values. That documentation is for C++ and so has one function with 5 default parameter values. To cover for that, OpenCV Java wrapper has 6 methods. The error you are getting, ideally shouldn't be because of this.

Try below.

1. `capture.release()` is called in loop. Release should happen outside while loop. Use like
   `while( !done ) { ... }`
2. After `capture.retrieve(frame);`, add `if( frame.empty() ) { continue; }`

Comment: Thank you for the help :) anyways I could correct it and get the required output. Still learning the basics in OpenCV with Java.